# Do you need to overwrite hash and eql? when overwriting == operator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop

In languages like Java and C#, if you are override equality operators, you must override the hash method as well.

> Whenever a.equals(b), then a.hashCode() must be same as b.hashCode()

As far I understand, some internal data structures in these languages rely on the condition above to hold true in order to function correctly.

I wonder if the same is true in Ruby. Do you need to override `hash` method of the object when overriding `==` operator? I heard that you need to override the `eql?` when overriding `==`. What are the reasons behind those claims, and what would happen if you won't override those?

Comment: I'm not sure there's an authoritative guide, but you should ensure all of these are in sync or your code might get very *strange*. Inconsistencies like this are like saying 1+1=2 but 2-1=0.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has 3 equality methods `==`, `eql?` and `equal?`. At the base `Object` class they all do the same, but for the more specific classes they provide class-specific semantics.

What they compare is dependant on the developer who implemented the class, but nevertheless, there is a convention.

#### `==` — Value comparison

True when two objects have the same value.

```
2.2.3 :011 > 5 == 5.0  
 => true 
2.2.3 :012 > 'test' == 'test'  
 => true 
2.2.3 :013 > { a: 10 } == { a: 10.0 }  
 => true 
2.2.3 :014 > :test == :test  
 => true 
2.2.3 :016 > ['a', :test, 10] == ['a', :test, 10.0]  
 => true
```

#### `eql?` — Value and type comparison

True when two objects have the same value and type

```
2.2.3 :028 > 'test'.eql? 'test'  # Strings  
 => true 
2.2.3 :029 > 5.eql? 5  # Fixnums  
 => true 
2.2.3 :030 > 5.eql? 5.0  # Fixnum & Float  
 => false 
2.2.3 :032 > { a: 10 }.eql?({ a: 10 })  # Hash  
 => true 
2.2.3 :033 > { a: 10 }.eql?({ a: 10.0 })  
 => false
```

#### `equal?` — Reference comparison

True when two objects share the same memory reference. This method should never be overridden.

```
2.2.3 :017 > 'test'.equal? 'test'  
 => false 
# Each string is an independent object even if they share content
2.2.3 :018 > :test.equal? :test  
 => true 
# Symbols share reference if they have the same content
2.2.3 :019 > 1.equal? 1  
 => true 
2.2.3 :020 > [].equal? []  
 => false 
2.2.3 :021 > a = 'test'  
 => "test" 
2.2.3 :022 > b = a    # b is a reference to the same object as a  
 => "test" 
2.2.3 :023 > b.equal? a  
 => true
```

If you are just overriding the `==` you don't *need* to override the `hash` method, but you *should*, in case the `eql?` or `equal?` methods get called.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't ***need*** to override `eql?` and `hash` methods.

However, as tadman mentioned, you *should* override them. You don't know how eql? might be used, and if you don't override hash then you will get strange results if you use the object as a hash key. See this [blog post](http://belighted.com/en/blog/overriding-equals-equals).

Having said all that, you brought up an interesting point:

> In Java and C#, you must override the hash method as well.

What happens if you don't override the hash method? Will it fail to compile, or is it a poor practice?

It feels like in Ruby there are very few hard and fast rules like this. I wonder if Ruby has a different paradigm compared to languages like C#, Java and C++. Perhaps the paradigm is different because Ruby is duck typed and does not have a separate compile process.